# Command line arguments and read file/print text in C

Tags: c, process, command-line-arguments

I am trying to work with command line arguments and parsing a text file in C. Basically I want to be able to put in two numbers, like, 1 and 4 and have it read a column of a text file then print it to stdout. I want to be able to do something like take this:

```
PID   TTY        TIME     CMD
449   ttys000    0:00.35 -bash
1129  ttys001    0:00.35 -bash
25605 ttys001    0:00.15  vi prog.c
6132  ttys002    0:00.11 -bash
6208  ttys002    0:00.03  vi test
```

And do:

```
./your_prog 1 4 < data.txt 

PID CMD
449 bash
1129 -bash
25605 vi
6132 -bash 
6208 vi
```

So I need to enter the the columns i want to print out, redirect the file in "data.txt" and have it process the file and print like so.

So far I have this for my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(int argc, char **argv){
//int row = argc[0];
//int col = argc[1];
//if number entered is less than one, re-enter

int i;
for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
  printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
}
if(argc < 1){
  fprintf(stderr, "Enter a valid input");

  //quit
  return 1;
} 
else{   
  char ch[256];
  //ch[255] = '\0';

    while(fgets(ch, 256, stdin) != NULL){
      printf("%s", ch);
    }
  } 
  return 1;
}
```

but am not sure if I am on the correct track and am confused as to what to do next. I am new to C, so I apologize if this is an easy question.

Comment: You seem to have a good start, especially for a C newbie.  Note that `argv[0]` will be the name of the program.  Its arguments, if any, will be presented in `argv[1]` ... `argv[argc - 1]`.

Comment: Although you are using `fgets()` correctly, it does limit you to a fixed maximum line length, and it will truncate long lines without much warning.  If you are using GCC and the GNU C library then you could consider using the `getline()` function instead.

Comment: Unless you intend to assume fixed column widths, you'll have to split lines somehow.  If you're willing to assume that there is some kind of separator between columns, such as whitespace, then you can break the input line into columns via the standard `strtok()` function.  Do note, however, that some values in column 4 of your example input contain internal whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started, this improves the way you gather the command line information. Note the first argument `argv[0]` is the name of the executable itself. Bear in mind comments above, I haven't improved any further. Syntax is `progname filename col1 col2`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fatal(char *msg) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    exit (1);
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    int col1, col2;
    FILE *fp;
    char ch[256];

    if(argc < 4)
        fatal("Need three arguments");

    if (sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &col1) != 1)
        fatal("Argument 1 error");

    if (sscanf(argv[3], "%d", &col2) != 1)
        fatal("Argument 2 error");

    printf("Read columns %d and %d from file %s\n", col1, col2, argv[1]);
    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
        fatal("Unable to open file");

    // process the file
    while (fgets(ch, 256, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", ch);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am having an issue where the above code shows: `if (sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &col1) != 1)
        fatal("Argument 1 error");
 ` is that setting argv[2] to col1?

Comment: @ksudood No, it is setting `col1` from `argv[2]`. The array of string pointers `argv[]` contains the arguments you entered on the command line, except `argv[0]` which is what the first loop in you program shows. `sscanf()` and friends returns the number of fields successfully scanned.

Comment: Ok I managed to get it to print out my whole text file. How would you suggest that I begin to process and pick apart the file. Like if I wanted to only print col1 like this:
`PID  449  
1129   
25605  
6132  
6208`

Comment: Have a read of the comments from @JohnBollinger, look up `strtok()` and try something yourself. In one of his remarks he says you might lose part of the field - but you *do* show the partial field in your question's example. Start by separating *all* the fields and printing them out again, before trying to select the ones you really want. Step by step, easy do.

Comment: I have gotten the strtok() to parse apart my text file. Now how would I go about telling it what columns to print? I will post part of the code I have so far.

Comment: Just count the number of the field, and ignore it if it is not `col1` or `col2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have so far. I can get it to parse apart then I can put it back how it was, but for the life of me I cant figure out how to tell it to print only the first column. If I could have some direction, then I could figure out how to do the rest, but I can find anything. Here is what code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv){
int col1, col2;
int size = 512;
char ch[size];
char *temp[size];

char *token;

if(argc == 1){
fprintf(stderr, "I need more!\n");
return 1;
}

else{
//test to see what is stored

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);   
  }

  if(sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &col1) != 1) return 1;
  if(sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &col2) != 1) return 1;   

  while(fgets(ch, size, stdin) != NULL){
    //get 1st token
    token = strtok(ch, " ");
      while(token != NULL){
        printf(" %s", token);
        temp[i++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
      }   
    } 
    return 0;   
  }
}
```

Comment: Just count the number of the field *on each line* and ignore it if it is not `col1` or `col2`