# How to make a program work on different text files in C

Tags: c, performance, tokenize

I am trying to work with command line arguments and parsing a text file in C. Basically I want to be able to put in two numbers, like, 1 and 4 and have it read a column of a text file then print it to stdout. I want to be able to do something like take this:

```
PID   TTY        TIME     CMD
449   ttys000    0:00.35 -bash
1129  ttys001    0:00.35 -bash
25605 ttys001    0:00.15  vi    prog.c
6132  ttys002    0:00.11 -bash
6208  ttys002    0:00.03  vi    test
```

And do:

```
./your_prog 1 2 5 < data.txt 

PID   TTY
449   ttys000
1129  ttys001
25605 ttys001 prog.c
6132  ttys002 
6208  ttys002 test
```

I have for the most part gotten the program to be able to print out the correct columns based on the command line arguments. However, my real question is, if I was given a text file with an unknown amount of columns and was asked to process it, how would I go about making it work on most, if not all text files of this format?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
int col1, col2;
int size = 512;
char ch[size];
char *temp[size];
char *my_array[size];
int field_count = 0;

char *token;

if(argc == 1){
  fprintf(stderr, "I need more!\n");
  return 1;
}
else{
  //test to see what is stored
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);   
  }

if(sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &col1) != 1) return 1;
if(sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &col2) != 1) return 1;   

while(fgets(ch, size, stdin) != NULL){
  //get 1st token
  token = strtok(ch, " ");
  while(token != NULL){
    //printf(" %s", token);
    temp[i++] = token;
    my_array[field_count] = token;
    field_count++;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  } 
  if(col1 == 1){
    printf("%s\n", my_array[0]);
  }  
} 
  return 0;   
}
}
```

Comment: This has been done with cut http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut

Comment: FYI, what you are trying to do is exactly what `cut` does.  See http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut.

Comment: This is yesterday's question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505929/command-line-arguments-and-read-file-print-text-in-c), where I advised you to count the fields *on each line* and keep those that match the desired column numbers. Yet you are not resetting `field_count` at the start of each text line. You are almost there... but if you don't know what a file contains, how do you know what columns to capture? Perhaps the command line arguments should specify column *heading text*, and then you parse the first line to determine what column *numbers* you wish to keep in subsequent lines.

Comment: the variable 'size' should be a #define size (512)

Comment: BTW note your very first test `if(argc == 1)`. You want two column numbers, so the test should be `if(argc != 3)`

Comment: the lines from the input file are terminated (normally) with '\n'.  after the fgets(), which will include the newline in the 'ch' buffer, the code (probably) should replace that newline with a '\0' so if the code is trying to get the last field on a line, it will not get the field + a newline.

Comment: @user3629249 OP is using `strtok()` so the delimiter set should be `" \t\n"` which will deal with it.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I agree that would work.  I was just noting that the newline needed consideration within the code.

Comment: when running this program, the program will 'suddenly' exit on any failure, with out telling the user what is wrong.  Perhaps including an appropriate printf() statement or two to let the user know the source of the problem would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice you are trying to capture the field by storing the pointer returned from `strtok()` in an array, but that pointer's data is transient: you would need to have a string array to copy the actual text into. I have reworked and simplified your quite accomplished attempt, please try this which just prints the captured fields - your next step could be to write them to a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE    512                     // for buffer size

void fatal(char *msg) {                     // easy  & informative getout
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    exit (1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int col1, col2;
    char ch[BUF_SIZE];
    int field_count;
    char delims[] = " \t\n";                // might be tabs and newlines
    char *token;

    if(argc != 3)                           // check exact number of args
        fatal ("I need more!");
    if(sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &col1) != 1)
        fatal ("Bad first argument");
    if(sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &col2) != 1)
        fatal ("Bad second argument");
    printf("Capturing fields %d and %d\n", col1, col2);

    while(fgets(ch, BUF_SIZE, stdin) != NULL){
        field_count = 1;                    // reset field count
        printf("Fields captured:");
        token = strtok(ch, delims);
        while(token != NULL){
            if (field_count == col1 || field_count == col2)
                printf(" %s", token);
            field_count++;
            token = strtok(NULL, delims);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: When this program runs, at least for the example .txt file above, it has 5 columns of data. If I want to to print the first column only, then i would pass 1, or if I wanted the first two then I would pass 1 2 in the command line params so on and so forth. I want this only print to stdout, not a text file. So doing it the above way, would accomplish this?

Comment: This insists on two columns as you asked. If you only want one column enter `runprog 1 1` that is, with two identical arguments. If you want a variable number of columns, just process at least 1 argument and build an array of column numbers, with total number of fields to be captured (as in the array). Then in the `strtok()` loop, test  `field_count` against all the column/field numbers in that array, instead of the specific two columns you asked for. Listen: step-by-step, you will get there. But you need to write it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if these are dumb questions. I am used to writing in C# and so C is a little hard to get my mind around.